# Download and delete documents using Powershell

Tags: powershell, document-library

I'm looking to build a Powershell script that does the following to all documents in a SharePoint 2010 document library:

1. Downloads the document to a network file share
2. Deletes the original document in the document library

I started experimenting with the following:

```
$Url = "http://sharepoint2010/myweb/Shared%20Documents/aaa.txt"
$Path = "C:\test\aaa.txt"
$Username = ""
$Password = ""

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
```

However I get "(401) Unauthorized" exceptions even if I execute this on the SharePoint server.  Note that this script will execute on a schedule running on a SharePoint WFE server.

Comment: I am getting error:
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path
and sometimes it does not copy anything but deletes the folders and files
Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if you planing to create a timer job then better investigate how to do it using c# instead of powershell and when the code is running on a timer job it will use the farm account so you wont need to impersonate any account.

Here is a good example of moving/copying documents using the SharePoint object model
http://geek.hubkey.com/2007/12/move-sharepoint-document-library-files.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey Renzo, I agree that doing it by code would be a good approach but I need do achieve this through a script.  By timer job I didn't mean SharePoint time job, just a scheduled task through Windows.  Thanks for your response though!

Comment: Hi Jonny,
Fair enough  :)
How about using the unc path instead ? and then you can use the move-item command-let for example to move a file should be as simple as 

Move-Item "\\testserver\DavWWWRoot\Shared Documents\test.txt" "c:\"

This will move the test.txt to your c drive

you will need to ensure that your schedule task "run as" its set to a user with access to SharePoint and to the folder where you are saving you files

Comment: Great suggestion, I'm testing that out and will let you know if it works...

Answer (score 8):

Since I don't see PowerShell script that downloads and deletes all files from document library to local or network drive in any of the answers I will post one (this script also keeps folder structure on destination drive):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$destination = "C:\\test\\"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://sharepoint2010/myweb/"
$list = $web.GetList("http://sharepoint2010/myweb/Shared%20Documents/")

function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }
        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
        #Delete file by deleting parent SPListItem
        $list.Items.DeleteItemById($file.Item.Id)
    }
}

#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}

#Delete folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    try {
        $list.Folders.DeleteItemById($folder.ID)
    }
    catch {
        #Deletion of parent folder already deleted this folder
        #I really hate this
    }
}
```

Permission issues? Just run it on SharePoint server as admin and it will work :)

Comment: Permission issues? Resolve them by applying the correct permissions to the appropriate folders and sites. Never recommend a "just run as admin" mindset to a production environment. Good script, though.

Comment: James, I totally agree with you about permissions. I was a bit annoyed with other answers elaborating about permissions and not about script that was in original question.

Comment: Arguably, the question was he was getting a 401, so that does relate to perms, but a full, usable script block is a valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this impersonating the farm account, you won't (by default) have access to the content of sites.

you will have to impersonate an account which has access to that site, but then you have the issue of storing credentials in a script, which is very ill-advised (particularly if it's farm account credentials you have stored in there).

Is there any particular reason why you need this ran as a script?

Comment: Hello, the motivation to do this by script is for simple management and scheduling.  There are also budget constraints associated with developing custom code.  If this can't easily be achieved through powershell then I'll have to consider alternatives...

Comment: The scheduling and management (enable/disabling) for Timer Jobs can easily be set up in a secure environment within Central Administration. With your business case for development of custom code, I'd suggest presenting the risk of having the entire SharePoint configuration username and password stored in a plain text file against having it locked away within the (tried and tested) security of SharePoint Central Administration.

Comment: If the task is running through the context of the Windows Task Scheduler, would it not pass on those credentials and not require the username/password to be embedded into the script?

Comment: Yep, you'd probably need not create a credential object like your sample code above, and Renzo's suggestion may work even better (he sits behind me in the office, I know his PowerShell is good :) )