# Powershell command to copy file from Document Library to a fileshare

Tags: powershell

I have created a WorkFlow to create a document populating it with data from a list.
I now need a powershell script that can copy the file in the document library to a file share on our server.

I am new to using powershell in SharePoint, is this possible with a script?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: @SebastienStettler I did find a post on this site http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6511/download-and-delete-documents-using-powershell
It included a script which I have altered which copies files however how would I change it to only fetch a single file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method.

```
$fileUrl = url for file on sharepoint

$destinationfolder = destinationFolder


    function ProcessURL {
        param($fileUrl,$destinationfolder)
        $pathToTry = "http://www.mysharepointsite.com/somesite"
        $site = New-Object -Type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite -ArgumentList $pathToTry
        $web = $site.OpenWeb()  
        $file = $web.GetFile($fileUrl)
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }
        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
        #Delete file by deleting parent SPListItem
        $list.Items.DeleteItemById($file.Item.Id)
        $web.Close()
        $site.Close()
    }
```

Comment: Where are we passing Username and Password? or How do we pass Username and Password?

Comment: @AXA240778 You shouldn't need a username/password.  This should be ran on the SharePoint server while logged in with an account that has the necessary privileges and you shouldn't get prompted.  If you are, you may need to check your privileges.

Comment: Thanks @vapcguy

Comment: @AXA240778 One caveat:  I noticed if you just specify the URL directly & try to go to it directly without properly setting up your objects, I could see how you might get prompted. This happens on an HttpRequest, for example, if you don't include `CredentialsCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`.  `SPSite` & `SPWeb` must be appropriately defined, above.  It should be:  `$pathToTry = "http://mysharepointsite.com/somesite" $site = New-Object -Type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite -ArgumentList $pathToTry
  $web = $site.OpenWeb() ` and then you need to close them at the end: `$web.Close()
  $site.Close()`

Comment: @AXA240778 Added an edit to the answer to make it functional, with those lines, to demonstrate.

Comment: Thansk much @vapcguy