# How to move SharePoint 2007 data to Fileshare on a timely manner

Tags: 2007

I have MOSS farm,DR team does yearly DR excerises and they have a question at the time of Disaster,since all the data is stored in SharePoint,Assuming that DR team's SharePoint site wil be down during the Disaster and the documents wont be available so they wont be able to carry out there DR excercise

Now they want is can the data from there DR Site Collection be copied on a timely basis over to Fileshare is that even possible can this be done using OOTB features, we are on code freeze now, can this be done without Coding.

Please advise.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about use "Explorer View" to copy and paste files down to local drive?

Also, here you found a powershell script to download the files from Sharepoint with structure. However I am not so sure SP2007 can run it. Also you need to install additional patch if win2003 is using. [Download and delete documents using Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6511/download-and-delete-documents-using-powershell)

Hope it helps.